# How can I output to the same txt file I used to input in java?

Tags: java, printwriter

I want to "overwrite" what's in the input file and replace it with the updated information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can read the whole text file, then close it, do so - then use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`, (`FileOutputStream` will overwrite by default).

If you need to read and write at the same time, you should write to a different file, then delete the "old" file and rename the "new" file into place.